# selenium wait until colour changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need my code to wait until a button has changed colour.
I have used the below code however it sometimes fails because the item is no longer accessible (due to the postback).

To give an overview on what I'm trying to do:

When I click a save button on a website, everything turns grey for an unknown amount of time and then an asp.net postback is used. With selenium I'm trying to wait until a button is no longer grey and the postback has completed. The only way of telling If the postback is finished is if the colour is no longer grey.

---

**Code:**

```
def element_colour_check (self, locator, expected_color):
    # loop to retry if element is still loading
    for f in range(0,10)
        try:
            element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(locator)
            hex_color = Color.from_string(element.value_of_css_property("background-color")).hex

            #check to see if element is correct colour
            if (hex_color == expected_color) == True:
                return True
            else:
                sleep(1)
                continue

        except Exception as e:              
            sleep(1)
            continue
    raise self.insert_error("Element did not change colour")
```

**Calling the function:**

```
element_color_loading_check("save_btn", "#17a2b8")
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" name="save_btn" id=" save_btn " class="btn btn-info col-sm-12" value="Home">
```

---

Please note, the class name does not change when the buttons are grey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Selenium's [`Wait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) which is designed for such a scenario. Their example of a custom expected condition is very close to what you're after. You might even be able to get away with using the `presence_of_element_located` expected condition with a [CSS locator](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html?highlight=css#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) (`By.CSS`)

You could alter this logic to your own from their example.

```
    if self.css_class in element.get_attribute("class"):
        return element
```

Comment: i previously tried this but i couldnt get it to work. i must have had a slight typo. I now have it working with the following code:
`def __call__(self, driver):
                    element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)   # Finding the referenced element
                    print(Color.from_string(element.value_of_css_property("background-color")).hex)
                    if self.css_class in Color.from_string(element.value_of_css_property("background-color")).hex:
                        return element
                    else:
                        return False`